# Use javascript to increment score

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to javascript and my question seems very easy for someone, but I am stuck with the score increment of a correct answer for one time.

example: for my first question, the answer is Paris. if i write Paris in text box score should be incremented by 1 and for second question, answers is France and if i write France in text box score should be incremented by 1. This should be done only once i.e., if i delete Paris and Write again Paris Score should not be incremented.

```
<div id="score">score : 0</div>
<input type="text" id="question"/>
<input type="text" id="question1"/>

var score = 0;

$("#question").blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Paris')

    score++;

});

$("#question1").blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'France')

    score++;


});
```

Comment: Everybody wants your +1 so much! You will see a lot of people trying to answer that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would move the scoring into a function, this way if they change a correct answer back to an incorrect one it will then not be scored:

```
function checkResults() {
    var score = 0;
    if ($('#question').val() == 'Paris') {
        score++;
    }

    if ($('#question1').val() == 'France') {
        score++;
    }

    $('#score').text('score: ' + score);
}

$('input').blur(checkResults);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/LWE9U/)

[Make inputs case insensitive](http://jsfiddle.net/LWE9U/1/)

Comment: Hi Pete, thanks for the reply, ur code is working fine as required but wat about case sensitive letters. i tried using with if ($('#question').val() == 'Paris', 'paris')  and not working. can u tel me wats going wrong wit case sensitive...

Comment: Is it possible for decrement of score. I Tried with score=10; and then instead of score++ i tried --score and score-- but the score is decreasing only until 9. its not decreasing below 9. can u please tel wats wrong wit decrement...

Comment: Sorry to disturb with my stupid questions. I am just experimenting to see how the code executes.Only Decrement of score should be done whether the answer is correct or worng. even if i just click on the text-box and not entered any thing, then also the score should be decremented. i named it as negative score.  Here is wat i done http://jsfiddle.net/LWE9U/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can add an attribute to the text box if the question has been answered :

```
<input type="text" id="question" data-answered="true"/>
```

Comment: I think OP would appreciate to know how to read / set data attributes in jQuery.
It should also be noted, that you're technically not allowed to update data values in HTML5 (this means you still need to remove and re-build the input)

Answer (score 1):

You could keep track of which questions you answered with a score model like this:

```
var questions = [
  {
    fieldId : "#question",
    correctAnswer : "Paris",
    enteredAnswer : null,
  },
  {
    fieldId : "#question1",
    correctAnswer : "France",
    enteredAnswer : null,
  },
];
```

then, you could do this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //we need to wait until the document is loaded, or our elements will not be available yet
  $(document).ready(function(){
     //for each of the question input fields, when they blur(), we do the following:
     $(".questionclass").blur(function()
     {
         //we start counting the score
         var countedScore = 0;
         //we iterate through all the questions in our question model
         for(var i =0; i < questions.length; i++)
         {
            //we fetch the current question
            var activeQuestion = questions[i];

            //if there is no answer entered for that question
            if(activeQuestion.enteredAnswer == null)
            {
              //we find the field that should contain the answer to this question
              var questionField = $(activeQuestion.fieldId);

              //we then check if the user actualy inputted a value in that field.
              if(questionField.val() != "")
              {
                //if he did, we update the entered answer in our model
                activeQuestion.enteredAnswer = questionField.val();
              }
            }

            //if this question has the right answer
            if(activeQuestion.enteredAnswer == activeQuestion.correctAnswer)
            {
               //we increment the counted score
               countedScore++;
            }
         }
         alert("your score is " + countedScore);
     });
  });
</script>

<input type="text" name="something" id="question" class="questionclass"></input>
<input type="text" name="something" id="question1" class="questionclass"></input>
```

Comment: This is probably too advanced for the OP, but much more robust than the other answers that use individual variables to track the answered state.

Comment: keep in mind that this isn't a complete solution yet (UX wise). if the user clicks somewhere outside the edit field with an incomplete answer, that means that changing the answer afterwards will not change their score.

Comment: For OP : the cool thing about this, is that when you want to add questions, you only need to update your model and add a new input box, you can leave the rest of the code alone.

Answer (score 0):

```
questionScored = false;
question1Scored = false;

    $("#question").blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Paris' && questionScored == false){
            questionScored = true;
            score++;
        }

    });

    $("#question1").blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'France' && question1Scored == false){
            question1Scored = true;
            score++;
        }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.It doesn't seem to work. i just tested ur code in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Check if answer is given already saved or not.

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/MH9JD/)

```
var score, ans1, ans2;
score = ans1 = ans2 = 0;
$("#question").blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Paris') {
        if (!ans1) {
            ans1=1;
            score++;
        }
    }
    $("#score").text("score : " + score);
});

$("#question1").blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'France') {
        if (!ans2) {
            ans2=1;
            score++;
        }
    }
    $("#score").text("score : " + score);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply take a flag variable for tracking.

```
<div id="score">score : 0</div>
<input type="text" id="question"/>
<input type="text" id="question1"/>

var score = 0;
q = true
q1 = true

$("#question").blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Paris' && q==true){
        score++;
        q = false;
    }
});

$("#question1").blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'France' && q1==true){
        score++;
        q1 = false;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div id="score">score : 0</div>
<input type="text" id="question"/>
<input type="text" id="question1"/>

<script>
   function valid()
    {
        var score=0;
        if($("#question").val()=="Paris")
        score++;
        if($("#question1").val()=="France")
        score++;
        $("#score").text("score : "+score)
    }

 $("#question1,#question").blur(function(){
      valid()

  });
```

Comment: This is a good start, but the blur function has a syntax error and you should probably describe where and how to display the total score.